# XCTest: Is it possible to test SplashScreen in UI Test automation

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, automation-testing

I'm wondering if it is possible to test app's splash screen in UI Test automation.

My idea is to assert 1 UI element during splash screen presented, but sometimes it appear then disappear too fast, UI test just cannot catch it.

```
        // Launch the app for the first time
        startFreshApp()
        // Verify that splash screen is opened
        XCTAssert(onboardingPage.splashScreen.waitForExistence(timeout: 20))
```

Comment: Why would you need to test that the splash screen is opened? iOS does it for you, so need to test it